# AWS EC2 Cannot SSH even with port 22 open

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Try to learn AWS services I setup my own VPC with ipV4/v6.
Subnet and Security groups setup too (HTTP/S + SSH open on v4/v6)

When I try to `ssh -vvv -i myKey.pem ubuntu@xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

I got :

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ec2-35-157-94-119.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-35-157-94-119.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com [35.157.94.119] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 35.157.94.119 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-35-157-94-119.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

If try to `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-09e2830xxxxxx` or with the dashboard I can see my instance up and running with `Private and Public IPv4/v6` present and a `Public DNS`

Any idea why ?

Comment: Do you have port 22 open in the security group?

Comment: Yes =>
SSH TCP 22 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you did the following:

1. Create an IGW (Internet Gateway) and associate it with your VPC;
2. Add a route for `0.0.0.0/0` to go through the IGW;
3. Associate the subnet (the one you launched your EC2) with the correct routing table (the one containing `0.0.0.0/0 -> IGW`);

Comment: I have done 1 and 2 already. I just add the subnet. But cannot connect thru ssh.
My table route say : 10.10.0.0/16 -> local

Comment: Damn I miss read your point 3 ... 0.0.0.0/0 -> IGW ... My bad.
It's working now !

Comment: @Ragnar So If I add port 22 in my SG, I am enabling the inward traffic right? But If I didn't add the RTB entry - does it mean that my SSH request gets in to the instance and then stuck due to it cant find a way to send the response or the request doesn't reaches at all ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're e.g. spinning up a new instance from an old snapshot, it might just not work anymore with new instance types and other launch configurations etc. Check the status checks if you got 2 green ticks or is there possibly a problem (N.B. it might take quite a long for the checks to go actually red and before that it's just orange and it might not look that alarming and could easily go unnoticed):

[image: example of failed status checks]

More info about status checks https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html

Perhaps you can figure out a way to resolve the problem or alternatively spin a new instance and mount a volume created from the snapshot to that and copy over whatever you need to create a fresh working version out of your old snapshot.